# Retrieve a list of stored cards/tokens

Tags: opayo

I'm looking at a system for a client that is integrating with Sagepay and storing client cards. I'm wanting to retrieve a list of all stored cards/tokens from SagePay.

Anyone point me to documentation for this or give me a starter?

Cheers

Comment: Basically, you can't. This is why it is important not to just set `StoreToken` on authorization as a matter-of-course, because the tokens will simply build up in your account, never to be accessed again if you don't save a copy. You only want to save a token if the user explicitly asks to.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the reporting API - getTokenDetails should give you what you need. You'll need to know the token(s) you want the detail for, though.

[API Guide](https://www.sagepay.co.uk/file/6946/download-document/Reporting_and_Admin_API_Integration_Guideline_31012014.pdf)